# How to convert a -75mV signal into a +5V scaled signal?

Tags: voltage, sensor

I want to measure the current output from a 100A 12V alternator.

The signal input format required by the PLC controller is 0 to +5V DC.

To derive the base signal I have bought a DC shunt 75mV @ 100A.

I have also bought an adjustable DC signal amplifier to multiply the 75mV to 5V (a factor of 66.67). This is an LM386 audio amp from EBay.

But now I have a problem.

The DC amplifier grounds one side of the shunt taking the other side as the input.

This means I have to install the shunt on the negative side of the alternator's output. This means the system's ground will be slightly positive relative to the shunt output, the signal will be 0 to -75mV.

So the output from the amplifier will be 0 to -5V, where again the output is grounded on one side.

Is there a way I can opto isolate the output or input in which case I could put the shunt on the alternator's positive side, or how can I further convert the amplifier output from 0 to -5  to  0 to +5?

Comment: An audio amplifier normally accepts only AC signals and blocks any DC on it's input, so it is unsuited for this task. You might want to look into DC differential amplifiers.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to do this on a vehicle. Is this positive or negative earth? How are you powering the PLC and amplifier. Please provide a circuit diagram.

Comment: LM386 is an audio power amp designed to drive a small loudspeaker. Really not the right tool for this job. If you can ground one end of the sensor, use a rail to rail opamp in inverting configuration with a gain of 66. If you can't, take a look at instrumentation amplifiers, inamps.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that an LM386 is anything close to being an "adjustable DC signal amplifier"? It's nothing of the sort!

Comment: The purpose is a comprehensive monitoring system on a boat. Most data measured are Pressures, Temperatures & digital inputs, already established for the PLC Im using. But I haven't measured LV DC amps. Would a clamp on Hall effect sensor would work, I only need 5-10%  accuracy, but I need help with selecting a suitable sensor to convert  these DC amps to a 0 - 5VDC signal, where at 100a the voltage will be at least 3 to 4 volts, if not the full 5VDC. The PLC will read accurately to a resolution of ~ 0.25% of the 0-5vdc signal. I can scale the signal assuming the sensor is reasonably linear.

Comment: The power supply is from the boats 12 VDC system, of which there are Port & Stbd separate circuits, both sharing a common Negative earth. This 12 volts will run the  PLC directly, which in turn generates the 5VDC for passive sensors. The only issues I am having are this one for the Alternator output current, and a separate issue for converting the Alternator 3 phase pulses which are used to provide the  engine RPM reference signal, but I think I have a resolution for that parameter. The rest are pressure and temperature sensors with simple digital inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

If you really want to use a shunt, put it the positive wire and use a [high side current sense amplifier](https://eu.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Amplifier-ICs/Current-Sense-Amplifiers/_/N-6o48g), which is a cousin of an instrumentation amplifier with a tradeoff: it loses the feature "high input impedance", and gains the feature "being able to operate with the inputs way beyond its power supply rails". So you can supply it from 5VDC and it'll measure current on your shunt. Make sure you read the datasheets, get the right one, with suitable input common mode voltage.

If you don't want to waste power in a shunt, get a [current clamp](https://www.google.fr/search?q=current%20clamp&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjl6-uauOHsAhVLPhoKHXFnAskQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=current%20clamp&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzICCAAyBAgAEB4yBAgAEB4yBAgAEB4yBAgAEB4yBAgAEB4yBAgAEB4yBAgAEB4yBAgAEB4yBAgAEB46BAgjECc6BAgAEEM6BQgAELEDOggIABCxAxCDAVCF_wtYy5YMYJKcDGgAcAB4AIABTIgBtAaSAQIxM5gBAaABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=cbaeX6XvFMv8aPHOicgM&bih=1093&biw=2133) with a signal output. This isn't a clamp-on ammeter which just displays the current, instead it has wires that output voltages proportional to current.  You can also use a [Hall current sensor](https://www.lem.com/en/product-list?measurement=52&nominal_val=90-180) which does the same thing, in a smaller package.

Don't get the "AC only" kind, make sure it specifies "DC".

Personally I'd use the clamp or the sensor with a hole to thread the wire through, just to avoid messing with the thick wires.

To scale the clamp's output voltage to 5V, you can use any opamp which has an input common mode voltage that includes 0V, like LM324, LM358, etc. Or a rail to rail opamp.